# JSON Logic to Elasticsearch Query

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logic, opensearch

Before I invest time in building this, I wanted to find out if anyone as built or knows of a conversion too that will take jsonlogic (jsonlogic.com) and convert it to an elasticsearch query dsl structure.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: fwiw I haven't seen this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested I found this.
https://ukrbublik.github.io/react-awesome-query-builder/

It doesn't do directly a jsonlogic to elasticsearch dsl but does convert from it's own data structure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).